# How chrome's "save as Image" works internally?

Tags: image, google-chrome, browser

On a web-page, we have an image and provided a download button to download the image.

If the User downloads the image using the "download button" then image metadata information is preserved. (image original size is 1.8MB)

But the User downloads using "save as image" option (on right-click) then image metadata information is stripped completely. Even I see reduce in size as well. (Image size is 1.3 MB)

Could someone help me here to understand the chromes "save as image" functionality?

Image Meta info (Using download button)
[image]

Image Meta info (Using Save as browser option)
[image]

Comment: Can't repro. Can you set up an [MCVE]?

Comment: @Kaiido I really don't know how to reproduce here. "Download button" returns the exact image that is stored in the disk. But It is not the same image in the case of the "Save as Image" option. I have added the screenshot to show missing metadata information in these two images

Comment: Well you take the code that is used for the "Download button", and the one that shows the image where you can right-click "save as image". You paste it in a snippet (`<>`) and you link an image available online (wikimedia.org has a lot of these).